# javascript detect running program in computer client

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I've already googling for a whole day to finding how javascript detect running program in computer client.

I am using browser IE and using ActiveXObject to run some program that needed in my web. And in the browser, I need to detect running my program that already runnning.

Does anybody know the javascript code to detect running program?

Comment: Javascript can't do that for obvious security reasons. But your ActiveX object should be able to do that.

Comment: Does your program make any changes on the webpage? You could possibly trigger a DOM event by changing an element in the document.

Comment: @AustinMullins No, my program doesn't make any changes on the webpage, it just contain webBrowser that load the same URL from browser. So, when URL loaded on my program, it will run the same program.